# Does יו close a syllable?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

With a word like ידיו is the final syllable closed or open? Are the final letters a closed consonant or an extension of the vowel,  like a tripthong?

Comment: Even if it's just a yud ידי (the plural one, with kamatz patach) it's closed

Comment: This is just like a Mappik Hei.

Answer (score 3):

It is closed. See dagesh qal in [Vayiqra 7:30](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0302.htm):

> **יָדָ֣יו תְּבִיאֶ֔ינָה** אֵ֖ת אִשֵּׁ֣י יְהוָ֑ה אֶת־הַחֵ֤לֶב עַל־הֶֽחָזֶה֙ יְבִיאֶ֔נּוּ אֵ֣ת הֶֽחָזֶ֗ה לְהָנִ֥יף אֹת֛וֹ תְּנוּפָ֖ה לִפְנֵ֥י יְהוָֽה׃

or [Iyov 1:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2701.htm).